# QDateTime to QString with milliseconds in Qt3

Tags: qt, qstring, qt3, qdatetime

Is there a way in Qt3 to convert QDateTime into a QString and back to QDateTime, so that eventually QDateTime will contain information about milliseconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the [`toString`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.0/qdatetime.html#toString) function. The format parameter determines the format of the result string.

For example the following code will return only the seconds and the miliseconds.

```
QDateTime t = QDateTime::currentDateTime ();
QString s = t.toString("ss:zzz");
```

PS. You should consider porting your code to `Qt4`

Comment: Yes, your method works fine (+1). But i made a typo in question.  Now edited. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

```
QString DataList[100][100] ;
QDateTime AwbDateTime ;
AwbDateTime = QDateTime::fromString(DataList[i][9].left(19),Qt::ISODate) ;
```

This will work fine in Qt3